# Fat Arrow not a function

Tags: angular, typescript

When using Angular 4 and Typescript i have defines this function

```
   @Injectable()
   export class XService {
     display: (message?: string) => Promise<boolean>;    
   }

  @Component({
     templateUrl: './app/x/x.html',
     styleUrls: ['./app/x/x.component.css']
  })
  export class XEditComponent  { 
    constructor(private _xService: XService ) { }
    deleteX(): void {
         let msg = "Do you really want to delete !";
         this._xService.display(msg).then((responseOk) => {
         //.....
        });
   }
}
```

but am always getting a TypeError 'display' is not a function.

Comment: It would be useful if you'd add the part of the code that actually generates the error. How are you trying to execute this function?

Comment: You've declared `display` as a function, but what is assigned to it? If it's not assigned a value, it'll be `undefined` and the error you've described will be effected if you attempt to call it as a function.

Answer (score 3):

You have not actually defined a function. You have only defined its type. Right now `display` will be undefined.

Define the function:

```
export class XService {
    display: (message?: string) => Promise<boolean> = (message) => {  
      // Do something more useful here
      return Promise.resolve(true);
    }
}
```

Or you can remove the type declaration and let the compiler infer the type:

```
export class XService {
    display = (message: string | undefined): Promise<boolean> => {
        // Do something more useful here
        return Promise.resolve(true);
    }
}
```

Or you can change your declaration to method syntax instead of property syntax:

```
export class XService {
    display(message: string | undefined): Promise<boolean>  {
        // Do something more useful here
        return Promise.resolve(true);
    }
}
```